# Convert point to array using php function

Tags: php, split

**Convert point to array** using php function :-

example :

```
1. i am xxxxxx
2. i have a good happit
3. i am good boy
```

i want like to convert array,

```
[0] -> i am xxxxxx
[1] -> i have a good happit
[2] -> i am good boy
```

please help me...Thanks in advance

Comment: Which part of the code are you stuck with?

Comment: get the point from textarea field, i want to display the individual point from different place in the html. So i need to convert that point to array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there would be in the formatting you described.

```
$str = $textfield_input;
$text_row = explode("\n", $str); //Each row to $text_row
foreach($text_row as $line) {
    $row = explode(".", $line); 
    $array[] = $line[1];
}

var_dump($array);

array(
[0] => i am xxxxxx
[1] => i have a good happit
[2] => i am good boy 
)
```

Comment: thanks very much isnisn . I got the expected result from your code. thanks :). I give on up vote.